# how to make migration from classic Hybrid app to cordova based Hybrid app in MobileFirst?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

how to establish migration from classic Hybrid app to cordova based Hybrid app because the latest MF version supports only cordova based hybrid apps? Is IBM providing any tools for this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Migration Cookbook](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/) that provides (among other things) information about how to migrate MobileFirst 7.1 (or prior) hybrid application to a MobileFirst 8.0 Cordova application.  This page also describes the Migration Assistance tool that is provided to help with this process.